# Shinyproxy with PWA

Tags: r, shiny, progressive-web-apps, shinyproxy

I am trying to host a progressive web app (PWA) on a shinyproxy server using keycloak user authentication. However, the webmanifest cannot be loaded. Is there any advice how to host a PWA compatible shiny app on shinyproxy?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am afraid, that this question is of a more general nature: is it possible to host a PWA app with shiny proxy? Is there any viable example/tutorial?